# Create file in subdirectories that doesn't exist (../new_folder/new_folder/new_file.ext)

Tags: command-line, mkdir, touch

For now i use this:

```
mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e; 
touch a/b/c/d/e/file.abc;
```

Is there more efficient ways?

Comment: Short of creating a function/alias/wrapper script? Why?

Comment: What does "more efficient" mean to you?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller To create something like this /uploads/{{%user_id%}}/doc|or|pdf|img/file.txt,  create empty folders as alternative doesn't looks good;

Comment: Please do not close this question; it's not a made up problem -- otherwise the /usr/bin/install utility wouldn't have been invented, 30 or 35 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of tools used:  no.  `touch` will fail (rightly) if you are trying to operate in a directory that does not exist, and `mkdir` does precisely one thing:  create *directories*, not normal *files*.  Two different jobs mandate two different tools.

That said, if you're talking about efficiency in terms of the number of lines in a script, or the readability of one, you could put it into a function:

```
seedfile() {
   mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")"
   touch "$1"
}

seedfile /path/to/location/one/file.txt
seedfile /path/to/somewhere/else/file.txt
seedfile local/paths/work/too/file.txt
```

Comment: You might want to use ```&&``` to do the `touch` only if the directory exists.

Answer (score 3):

```
install -D src_file /tmp/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/dst_file
install -Dt /tmp/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i your_file
```

If you want just to touch an empty file:

```
install -D /dev/null /tmp/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/empty_file
```

Look at the [install(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/install) manpage; it has options for setting permissions, preserving timestamps, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
`mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e && touch $_/file.abc`
Always work for me.